# Showing complex transformations in a fluid way

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, graphing-functions, applications

It says it all in the title: I need to show how simple complex transformations (translations and dilations, or even both) affect shapes on the complex plane in a "fluid" way – that is, creating some kind of animation that shows how the transformation works by continuously bending/gliding an object from its original shape to its image. I'm working on Desmos, which offers the possibility of creating *sliders* (much like GeoGebra), which work like [this](http://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200914449/edit_slider.gif).

Translations are very simple. Starting from a complex number $x+iy$, translation by $a+ib$ (with $x,y,a,b \in \mathbb{R}$) means

$$\mathcal{T}(z) = (x+a) + i(y+b)$$

I can then add the glider $k$ to get

$$\mathcal{T}(z) = (x+ka) + i(y+kb), \quad 0 \le k \le 1$$

It's clear that when $k=0$ we have the identity transformation, and when $k=1$ the translation is over.

I'm having a hard time depicting *dilations* in the same way. Dilations by $a+ib$ take the form

$$\mathcal{D}(x+iy) = (ax-by) + i(bx+ay)$$

My thought was that I need to place $k$ in such a way that when $k=0$ the expression reverts to $x+iy$, and when $k=1$ the expression looks like the equation above. So I conjectured that this would work:

$$\mathcal{D}(x+iy) = (a^kx-kb^ky) + i(kb^kx+a^ky), \quad 0\le k\le 1$$

Yet the formula blows up whenever either $a$ or $b$ or both are negative, for non-natural $k$. Is there a nicer and more effective way to insert a slider in the dilation equation above?

**Addendum.** The objective would be having the means of depicting not just simple transformations but also *any* other function that can be found out there, given its real and imaginary parts. I'm looking especially at $f(z) = z^{-1}$, which would allow me to represent Möbius transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Dilation by $1$ is the identity function, so given a path from $1$ to $z = a+ib$ you obtain a continuous transformation from identity function to dilation by $z$. However, this transformation can look strange or ugly, depending on the path chosen.

Since complex multiplication is, geometrically, a scaling and a rotation, I would recommend to put $z$ into polar form $z = re^{i\varphi}$ and create a path from $1$ to $z$ by $\gamma(t) = tre^{it\varphi}$, and the final transformation looks like $(x+iy) tr e^{it\varphi}$. This way you get a continuous monotone scaling and rotation.

Unfortunatelly, I guess you cannot do such a transformation for $z^{-1}$ without passing some degenerate function in the middle, basically because $z^{-1}$ changes the orientation of the plane.